# CardView background color always white

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and have each item as `CardView`.

Unfortunately, the `CardView` here does not seem to change its background color. I tried in layout and programmatically as well but I have tried nothing seems to work.

I have been struggling for quite a while. I would appreciate it if someone could help me out with this issue.

Comment: card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white" check with this.

Comment: Need code to help

Comment: It's very long code hence I didn't post it. Let me post some relevant code.

Comment: While I was going through the code to post here, I found that somewhere I had put cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); which was the reason it always was white.

Answer (score 457, accepted):

If you want to change the card background color, use:

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@somecolor"
```

like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Edit:**
As pointed by @imposible, you need to include

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

in your root XML tag in order to make this snippet function

Comment: It worked for me when I used it like this --->   
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"

Comment: In that, have xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" included in your layout file.

Comment: I am using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`. Using `app:cardBackgroundColor="@somecolor"` worked for me, but `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@somecolor"` did not.

Answer (score 48):

You can do it either in XML or programmatically:

In XML:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/red"
```

Programmatically:

```
cardView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_color));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I solved it. I had changed the color programmatically somewhere which I couldn't spot.

Answer (score 14):

Kotlin for **XML**

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/red"
```

Programmatically:

```
cardName.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorGray));
```

Comment: Thank you. I used card.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.bla) previously which leads to very strange results. Getting the color via ContextCompat did the trick for me.

Comment: Correct, the key is to use the ContextCompat.getColor instead of setting directly the color.

Comment: Worked like a perfect charm

Answer (score 6):

**Android CardView background color**

XML code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:contentPadding="25dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#e4bfef"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="6dp" />
```

From the code

```
CardView card = findViewById(R.id.card_view_top);
card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6E6E6"));
```

Answer (score 3):

In XML:

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/your_color_name"
```

Both in **Java** and **Kotlin** you can do it programmatically:

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardViewBlue" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If still not visible in design view, you can temporarily remove these lines

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

or

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

If you need them, you can then add them back at build time

Answer (score 0):

If someone still gets the white color instead of the color he picked, just change the emulator you working on, that's works for me

Answer (score -2):

`app:cardBackgroundColor="#488747"`

use this in your card view and you can change a color of your card view

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
```

or

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
```